# SSIS/Azure Data Factory or OPENROWSET/BULK INSERT in Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-data-factory, bulkinsert, bcp, openrowset

I have a very simple csv file to import into Azure SQL DB table. Below are some properties:

1. CSV file is of around 1 GB and stored on FTP server
2. This need to be imported into a table and replaced on daily basis through a day-end job process

My Questions:

1. Should I use Azure Data factory to import this data or should I use OPENROWSET or BULK INSERT command directly from Azure SQL DB and schedule it a batch job?
2. Will there be a cost difference if I use ADF vs OPENROWSET/BULK INSERT/BCP? Which one will be cheaper?
3. Is there any issue in maintenance when compared with AD vs OPENROWSET/BULK INSERT/BCP